# run websocket-rails javascript client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, channel, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to retrieve data from a websocket using my own web server. The websocket server on the remote host runs websocket-rails. From the Websocket-rails github project page (https://github.com/websocket-rails) I used the javascript client code to put together a web socket client in a html file. That is, I copied the contents of all CoffeeScript files in /lib/assets/javascripts/websocket_rails on github to a single file and then compiled it with js2coffee.org (probably better solutions, but i'm quite a noob as you may have noticed by now). Then added a few lines to connect to the remote web socket and subscribe to a channel. (the channel part is actually why I use the Websocket-rails client, instead of a "normal" web socket connection. As I couldn't figure out how to subscribe to a channel after connecting through a "normal" websocket connection.)

so far so good. When I I use a browser and the code below, I can connect to a channel from the websocket on the remote host and the messages are send to the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


(function() {
  var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  this.WebSocketRails = (function() {
    function WebSocketRails(url, use_websockets) {
      this.url = url;
      this.use_websockets = use_websockets != null ? use_websockets : true;
      this.connection_stale = __bind(this.connection_stale, this);
      this.pong = __bind(this.pong, this);
      this.supports_websockets = __bind(this.supports_websockets, this);
      this.dispatch_channel = __bind(this.dispatch_channel, this);
      this.unsubscribe = __bind(this.unsubscribe, this);
      this.subscribe_private = __bind(this.subscribe_private, this);
      this.subscribe = __bind(this.subscribe, this);
      this.dispatch = __bind(this.dispatch, this);
      this.trigger_event = __bind(this.trigger_event, this);
      this.trigger = __bind(this.trigger, this);
      this.unbind = __bind(this.unbind, this);
      this.bind = __bind(this.bind, this);
      this.connection_established = __bind(this.connection_established, this);
      this.new_message = __bind(this.new_message, this);
      this.reconnect = __bind(this.reconnect, this);
      this.callbacks = {};
      this.channels = {};
      this.queue = {};
      this.connect();
    }

    WebSocketRails.prototype.connect = function() {
      this.state = 'connecting';
      if (!(this.supports_websockets() && this.use_websockets)) {
        this._conn = new WebSocketRails.HttpConnection(this.url, this);
      } else {
        this._conn = new WebSocketRails.WebSocketConnection(this.url, this);
      }
      return this._conn.new_message = this.new_message;
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.disconnect = function() {
      if (this._conn) {
        this._conn.close();
        delete this._conn._conn;
        delete this._conn;
      }
      return this.state = 'disconnected';
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.reconnect = function() {
      var event, id, old_connection_id, _ref, _ref1;
      old_connection_id = (_ref = this._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0;
      this.disconnect();
      this.connect();
      _ref1 = this.queue;
      for (id in _ref1) {
        event = _ref1[id];
        if (event.connection_id === old_connection_id && !event.is_result()) {
          this.trigger_event(event);
        }
      }
      return this.reconnect_channels();
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.new_message = function(data) {
      var event, socket_message, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        socket_message = data[_i];
        event = new WebSocketRails.Event(socket_message);
        if (event.is_result()) {
          if ((_ref = this.queue[event.id]) != null) {
            _ref.run_callbacks(event.success, event.data);
          }
          delete this.queue[event.id];
        } else if (event.is_channel()) {
          this.dispatch_channel(event);
        } else if (event.is_ping()) {
          this.pong();
        } else {
          this.dispatch(event);
        }
        if (this.state === 'connecting' && event.name === 'client_connected') {
          _results.push(this.connection_established(event.data));
        } else {
          _results.push(void 0);
        }
      }
      return _results;
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.connection_established = function(data) {
      this.state = 'connected';
      this._conn.setConnectionId(data.connection_id);
      this._conn.flush_queue();
      if (this.on_open != null) {
        return this.on_open(data);
      }
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.bind = function(event_name, callback) {
      var _base;
      if ((_base = this.callbacks)[event_name] == null) {
        _base[event_name] = [];
      }
      return this.callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.unbind = function(event_name) {
      return delete this.callbacks[event_name];
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.trigger = function(event_name, data, success_callback, failure_callback) {
      var event, _ref;
      event = new WebSocketRails.Event([event_name, data, (_ref = this._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0], success_callback, failure_callback);
      return this.trigger_event(event);
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.trigger_event = function(event) {
      var _base, _name;
      if ((_base = this.queue)[_name = event.id] == null) {
        _base[_name] = event;
      }
      if (this._conn) {
        this._conn.trigger(event);
      }
      return event;
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.dispatch = function(event) {
      var callback, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      if (this.callbacks[event.name] == null) {
        return;
      }
      _ref = this.callbacks[event.name];
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        callback = _ref[_i];
        _results.push(callback(event.data));
      }
      return _results;
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.subscribe = function(channel_name, success_callback, failure_callback) {
      var channel;
      if (this.channels[channel_name] == null) {
        channel = new WebSocketRails.Channel(channel_name, this, false, success_callback, failure_callback);
        this.channels[channel_name] = channel;
        return channel;
      } else {
        return this.channels[channel_name];
      }
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.subscribe_private = function(channel_name, success_callback, failure_callback) {
      var channel;
      if (this.channels[channel_name] == null) {
        channel = new WebSocketRails.Channel(channel_name, this, true, success_callback, failure_callback);
        this.channels[channel_name] = channel;
        return channel;
      } else {
        return this.channels[channel_name];
      }
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.unsubscribe = function(channel_name) {
      if (this.channels[channel_name] == null) {
        return;
      }
      this.channels[channel_name].destroy();
      return delete this.channels[channel_name];
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.dispatch_channel = function(event) {
      if (this.channels[event.channel] == null) {
        return;
      }
      return this.channels[event.channel].dispatch(event.name, event.data);
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.supports_websockets = function() {
      return typeof WebSocket === "function" || typeof WebSocket === "object";
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.pong = function() {
      var pong, _ref;
      pong = new WebSocketRails.Event(['websocket_rails.pong', {}, (_ref = this._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0]);
      return this._conn.trigger(pong);
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.connection_stale = function() {
      return this.state !== 'connected';
    };

    WebSocketRails.prototype.reconnect_channels = function() {
      var callbacks, channel, name, _ref, _results;
      _ref = this.channels;
      _results = [];
      for (name in _ref) {
        channel = _ref[name];
        callbacks = channel._callbacks;
        channel.destroy();
        delete this.channels[name];
        channel = channel.is_private ? this.subscribe_private(name) : this.subscribe(name);
        channel._callbacks = callbacks;
        _results.push(channel);
      }
      return _results;
    };

    return WebSocketRails;

  })();


  /*
  The Event object stores all the relevant event information.
   */

  WebSocketRails.Event = (function() {
    function Event(data, success_callback, failure_callback) {
      var attr;
      this.success_callback = success_callback;
      this.failure_callback = failure_callback;
      this.name = data[0];
      attr = data[1];
      if (attr != null) {
        this.id = attr['id'] != null ? attr['id'] : ((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0;
        this.channel = attr.channel != null ? attr.channel : void 0;
        this.data = attr.data != null ? attr.data : attr;
        this.token = attr.token != null ? attr.token : void 0;
        this.connection_id = data[2];
        if (attr.success != null) {
          this.result = true;
          this.success = attr.success;
        }
      }
    }

    Event.prototype.is_channel = function() {
      return this.channel != null;
    };

    Event.prototype.is_result = function() {
      return typeof this.result !== 'undefined';
    };

    Event.prototype.is_ping = function() {
      return this.name === 'websocket_rails.ping';
    };

    Event.prototype.serialize = function() {
      return JSON.stringify([this.name, this.attributes()]);
    };

    Event.prototype.attributes = function() {
      return {
        id: this.id,
        channel: this.channel,
        data: this.data,
        token: this.token
      };
    };

    Event.prototype.run_callbacks = function(success, result) {
      this.success = success;
      this.result = result;
      if (this.success === true) {
        return typeof this.success_callback === "function" ? this.success_callback(this.result) : void 0;
      } else {
        return typeof this.failure_callback === "function" ? this.failure_callback(this.result) : void 0;
      }
    };

    return Event;

  })();


  /*
   Abstract Interface for the WebSocketRails client.
   */

  WebSocketRails.AbstractConnection = (function() {
    function AbstractConnection(url, dispatcher) {
      this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
      this.message_queue = [];
    }

    AbstractConnection.prototype.close = function() {};

    AbstractConnection.prototype.trigger = function(event) {
      if (this.dispatcher.state !== 'connected') {
        return this.message_queue.push(event);
      } else {
        return this.send_event(event);
      }
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.send_event = function(event) {
      if (this.connection_id != null) {
        return event.connection_id = this.connection_id;
      }
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.on_close = function(event) {
      var close_event;
      if (this.dispatcher && this.dispatcher._conn === this) {
        close_event = new WebSocketRails.Event(['connection_closed', event]);
        this.dispatcher.state = 'disconnected';
        return this.dispatcher.dispatch(close_event);
      }
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.on_error = function(event) {
      var error_event;
      if (this.dispatcher && this.dispatcher._conn === this) {
        error_event = new WebSocketRails.Event(['connection_error', event]);
        this.dispatcher.state = 'disconnected';
        return this.dispatcher.dispatch(error_event);
      }
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.on_message = function(event_data) {
      if (this.dispatcher && this.dispatcher._conn === this) {
        return this.dispatcher.new_message(event_data);
      }
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.setConnectionId = function(connection_id) {
      this.connection_id = connection_id;
    };

    AbstractConnection.prototype.flush_queue = function() {
      var event, _i, _len, _ref;
      _ref = this.message_queue;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this.trigger(event);
      }
      return this.message_queue = [];
    };

    return AbstractConnection;

  })();


  /*
   HTTP Interface for the WebSocketRails client.
   */

  WebSocketRails.HttpConnection = (function(_super) {
    __extends(HttpConnection, _super);

    HttpConnection.prototype.connection_type = 'http';

    HttpConnection.prototype._httpFactories = function() {
      return [
        function() {
          return new XDomainRequest();
        }, function() {
          return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }, function() {
          return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }, function() {
          return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP");
        }, function() {
          return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      ];
    };

    function HttpConnection(url, dispatcher) {
      var e;
      this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
      HttpConnection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      this._url = "http://" + url;
      this._conn = this._createXMLHttpObject();
      this.last_pos = 0;
      try {
        this._conn.onreadystatechange = (function(_this) {
          return function() {
            return _this._parse_stream();
          };
        })(this);
        this._conn.addEventListener("load", this.on_close, false);
      } catch (_error) {
        e = _error;
        this._conn.onprogress = (function(_this) {
          return function() {
            return _this._parse_stream();
          };
        })(this);
        this._conn.onload = this.on_close;
        this._conn.readyState = 3;
      }
      this._conn.open("GET", this._url, true);
      this._conn.send();
    }

    HttpConnection.prototype.close = function() {
      return this._conn.abort();
    };

    HttpConnection.prototype.send_event = function(event) {
      HttpConnection.__super__.send_event.apply(this, arguments);
      return this._post_data(event.serialize());
    };

    HttpConnection.prototype._post_data = function(payload) {
      return $.ajax(this._url, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          client_id: this.connection_id,
          data: payload
        },
        success: function() {}
      });
    };

    HttpConnection.prototype._createXMLHttpObject = function() {
      var e, factories, factory, xmlhttp, _i, _len;
      xmlhttp = false;
      factories = this._httpFactories();
      for (_i = 0, _len = factories.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        factory = factories[_i];
        try {
          xmlhttp = factory();
        } catch (_error) {
          e = _error;
          continue;
        }
        break;
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    };

    HttpConnection.prototype._parse_stream = function() {
      var data, e, event_data;
      if (this._conn.readyState === 3) {
        data = this._conn.responseText.substring(this.last_pos);
        this.last_pos = this._conn.responseText.length;
        data = data.replace(/\]\]\[\[/g, "],[");
        try {
          event_data = JSON.parse(data);
          return this.on_message(event_data);
        } catch (_error) {
          e = _error;
        }
      }
    };

    return HttpConnection;

  })(WebSocketRails.AbstractConnection);


  /*
  WebSocket Interface for the WebSocketRails client.
   */

  WebSocketRails.WebSocketConnection = (function(_super) {
    __extends(WebSocketConnection, _super);

    WebSocketConnection.prototype.connection_type = 'websocket';

    function WebSocketConnection(url, dispatcher) {
      this.url = url;
      this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
      WebSocketConnection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      if (this.url.match(/^wss?:\/\//)) {
        console.log("WARNING: Using connection urls with protocol specified is depricated");
      } else if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
        this.url = "wss://" + this.url;
      } else {
        this.url = "wss://" + this.url;
      }
      this._conn = new WebSocket(this.url);
      this._conn.onmessage = (function(_this) {
        return function(event) {
          var event_data;
          event_data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          return _this.on_message(event_data);
        };
      })(this);
      this._conn.onclose = (function(_this) {
        return function(event) {
          return _this.on_close(event);
        };
      })(this);
      this._conn.onerror = (function(_this) {
        return function(event) {
          return _this.on_error(event);
        };
      })(this);
    }

    WebSocketConnection.prototype.close = function() {
      return this._conn.close();
    };

    WebSocketConnection.prototype.send_event = function(event) {
      WebSocketConnection.__super__.send_event.apply(this, arguments);
      return this._conn.send(event.serialize());
    };

    return WebSocketConnection;

  })(WebSocketRails.AbstractConnection);


  /*
  The channel object is returned when you subscribe to a channel.

  For instance:
    var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');
    var awesome_channel = dispatcher.subscribe('awesome_channel');
    awesome_channel.bind('event', function(data) { console.log('channel event!'); });
    awesome_channel.trigger('awesome_event', awesome_object);

  If you want to unbind an event, you can use the unbind function :
    awesome_channel.unbind('event')
   */

  WebSocketRails.Channel = (function() {
    function Channel(name, _dispatcher, is_private, on_success, on_failure) {
      var event, event_name, _ref;
      this.name = name;
      this._dispatcher = _dispatcher;
      this.is_private = is_private != null ? is_private : false;
      this.on_success = on_success;
      this.on_failure = on_failure;
      this._failure_launcher = __bind(this._failure_launcher, this);
      this._success_launcher = __bind(this._success_launcher, this);
      this._callbacks = {};
      this._token = void 0;
      this._queue = [];
      if (this.is_private) {
        event_name = 'websocket_rails.subscribe_private';
      } else {
        event_name = 'websocket_rails.subscribe';
      }
      this.connection_id = (_ref = this._dispatcher._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0;
      event = new WebSocketRails.Event([
        event_name, {
          data: {
            channel: this.name
          }
        }, this.connection_id
      ], this._success_launcher, this._failure_launcher);
      this._dispatcher.trigger_event(event);
    }

    Channel.prototype.destroy = function() {
      var event, event_name, _ref;
      if (this.connection_id === ((_ref = this._dispatcher._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0)) {
        event_name = 'websocket_rails.unsubscribe';
        event = new WebSocketRails.Event([
          event_name, {
            data: {
              channel: this.name
            }
          }, this.connection_id
        ]);
        this._dispatcher.trigger_event(event);
      }
      return this._callbacks = {};
    };

    Channel.prototype.bind = function(event_name, callback) {
      var _base;
      if ((_base = this._callbacks)[event_name] == null) {
        _base[event_name] = [];
      }
      return this._callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
    };

    Channel.prototype.unbind = function(event_name) {
      return delete this._callbacks[event_name];
    };

    Channel.prototype.trigger = function(event_name, message) {
      var event;
      event = new WebSocketRails.Event([
        event_name, {
          channel: this.name,
          data: message,
          token: this._token
        }, this.connection_id
      ]);
      if (!this._token) {
        return this._queue.push(event);
      } else {
        return this._dispatcher.trigger_event(event);
      }
    };

    Channel.prototype.dispatch = function(event_name, message) {
      var callback, _i, _len, _ref, _ref1, _results;
      if (event_name === 'websocket_rails.channel_token') {
        this.connection_id = (_ref = this._dispatcher._conn) != null ? _ref.connection_id : void 0;
        this._token = message['token'];
        return this.flush_queue();
      } else {
        if (this._callbacks[event_name] == null) {
          return;
        }
        _ref1 = this._callbacks[event_name];
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref1.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          callback = _ref1[_i];
          _results.push(callback(message));
        }
        return _results;
      }
    };

    Channel.prototype._success_launcher = function(data) {
      if (this.on_success != null) {
        return this.on_success(data);
      }
    };

    Channel.prototype._failure_launcher = function(data) {
      if (this.on_failure != null) {
        return this.on_failure(data);
      }
    };

    Channel.prototype.flush_queue = function() {
      var event, _i, _len, _ref;
      _ref = this._queue;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this._dispatcher.trigger_event(event);
      }
      return this._queue = [];
    };

    return Channel;

  })();

}).call(this);

//// Below is the code I added, the rest is compiled coffeeScript from the WebSocket-Rails github repository


testWebSocket = function() {
  var channelTicker, websocket;
  websocket = new WebSocketRails(wsUri);
  websocket.on_open = function(data) {
    console.log("Socket opened on " + wsUri + " :)");
  };
  channelTicker = websocket.subscribe("ticker");
  channelTicker.bind("ticker.new", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};

wsUri = "ws.remotehost.com:3456/websocket";

testWebSocket();




</script>



<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<p>all output in console</p>
```

So after this I thought, nice, lets figure out how to use a server to open the web socket connection and store all output in a mysql database. But this was a bit harder then I expected... I tried node.js to run the javascript from my html file on my web server. that doesn't work. 
It throws an error:

```
WebSocketRails.Event = (function() {
^
ReferenceError: WebSocketRails is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/tmp/wsBrowserClient.js:242:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

As far as I understand it now, the big difference between running js in the browser and in node.js is having or not having a DOM. The browser assigns variables to the `window` object but node.js can't do this.

So I have to change the javascript code to "node.js" javascript but can't find out where I have to start. My best guess would be with line

```
    this.WebSocketRails = (function() {
```

but to what should I change it? Hope someone can give me a hand. If someone can tell my how to subscribe to a channel with a "normal" webwocket and then use a web socket client written for node js, of course that would also be fine.

Or a way to 'just' run the code as it is now server-side with another method, that would also help.

To be clear I'm a noob at javascript. Do know a thing or two about php, but that don't help me much here...

BIG thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to line the file in exact same order other wise it will throw errors

`<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/websocket_rails.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/event.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/http_connection.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/websocket_connection.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/channel.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/websocket_rails/main.js?body=1`

This is the order I use and it works fine on my angular client.